# When do functions expecting maps silently return nil when passed a non-map argument?

Tags: exception, dictionary, clojure

I'm a bit surprised to see some functions silently returning `nil` (or the default value you pass) when you pass something that is not a map where a map is expected.

Take first the following doc and example, which works as I expected:

```
user> (doc dissoc)
-------------------------
clojure.core/dissoc
([map] [map key] [map key & ks])
  dissoc[iate]. Returns a new map of the same (hashed/sorted) type,
  that does not contain a mapping for key(s).
```

The first argument to `dissoc` must be a map as per the doc, so here's what happens:

```
user> (dissoc {:a 1 :b 2} :b)
{:a 1}
```

It works fine, I passed a map. Let's pass something that is not a map to that function whose doc says the first argument should be a map:

```
user> (dissoc 1 :b)
ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPersistentMap  clojure.lang.RT.dissoc (RT.java:758)
```

Fair enough, an exception is thrown at runtime and the issue is clear enough, this is the behavior I expected.

Let's now take another function:

```
user> (doc get)
-------------------------
clojure.core/get
([map key] [map key not-found])
  Returns the value mapped to key, not-found or nil if key not present.
```

The first argument to `get` must be a map as per the doc and here's what happens:

```
user> (get {:a 1} :a)
1
```

So far so good. Let's pass something that is not a map to that function whose doc says the first argument should be a map:

```
user> (get 42 :a)
nil
```

No exception. No nothing. Just a silent "failure".

How comes one function throws an exception when you pass something that is not a map and not the other, although both functions' docs clearly state that the first argument must be a map?

Is there a "rule" to know when, in Clojure, you'll get either exceptions or `nil` or should I just expect that kind of stuff to be inconsistent?

As a side-question: would Clojure and Clojure programs "break" if, say, *get* was modified to throw an exception instead of silently returning nil when you don't pass a map where you're supposed to?

Comment: `(get [4 3 2 1] 1)` => 3 `(get #{4 3 2 1} 1)` => 1 `(get "hello" 1)` => \e. it says "mapped", not that it needs a map. `get` is meant to work on all associative data structures.

Comment: @noisesmith: *([map key] [map key not-found])*   In both case the first argument is called "map".  Also, I know that the number 42 rocks but... How is the integer 42 an associative data structure?

Comment: The arg is named map, nothing says it must be a map.

Answer (score 3):

An exception *should* probably be thrown for a `get` on non-associative arguments as in your example:

```
(contains? 42 :a)
;=> IllegalArgumentException 

(get 42 :a)
;=> nil ??
```

This is an [open issue in Clojure's Issue Tracker](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1107). As stated in the issue description, the current behavior of returning a `nil` is most likely a bug and can obscure programming errors.

Comment: Would you consider java.lang.String to be associative? It doesn't satisfy the Clojure protocols, but is special cassed.

Comment: I'd consider it a special case. The exception should be thrown after all the cases are accounted for instead of returning null/nil.

Answer (score 1):

`get` is intended to work on all associative data structures. The language implementors could have chosen to check if the argument was associative, or made a white-list of all associative things that it could check, but instead it has a few special cases defined in clojure.lang.RT, and will also work on anything that implements Map or IPersistentSet or ILookup.

[the code is not too hard to grok](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L644)

Now, as to why it would silently return nil on something that implements none of these interfaces, this is an instance of a persistent Clojure design strategy of silently returning nil rather than failing. This decision definitely has tradeoffs, but it is a pervasive way Clojure does things.

Comment: if it's an instance of a persistent Clojure design strategy, then why does the *dissoc* example *not* silently return *nil* but throw an exception instead? My question is: is there a "rule" to know when you'll get exception or when you'll get *nil*? Are things simply totally inconsistent?

Comment: There is no rule that I know of. This is frankly one of my least favorite aspects of the Clojure language (I do love Clojure overall, but this is a wart as far as I am concerned).

Comment: The examples I can think of offhand of Clojure functions returning `nil` on "wrongly" typed arguments center around lookup (such as `get` and keyword lookup). `dissoc`, on the other hand, returns a new map; it would be inconsistent with its own signature if it instead returned a number or other arbitrary value.